# ExecuteNonQuery not working in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, executenonquery

I am building a database using Visual Studio 2008 c# and when I'm a trying to insert a new record into my database it appears that `ExecuteNonQuery` has not initialized. I copy my code, hope anyone can help me in this because I am new.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Nova\Nova\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
     cn.Open();
     cmd.CommandText = "insert into Database1.mdf(Codigo,Nombre,Cantidad,Tipo) values('"+comboBox1.Text+"','"+textBox3.Text+"','"+textBox1.Text+"','"+comboBox2.Text+"')";
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     cmd.Clone();
     cn.Close();
     MessageBox.Show("Acabas de agregar un producto");
 }
```

Comment: do you get exception ? share with us ?

Comment: You have to assign the connection for the command object.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Also, you should use a `using` block with classes that implement the IDisposable interface, especially with the SqlConnection class in order to close the connection in case of an exception.

Comment: Also, Database1.mdf is the name of the file. Do you have any tables defined in your database?

Comment: And what 'cmd.Clone(); was supposed to do? typo? (cmd.Close?...).

Answer (score 14):

You haven't set the connection to your command:

```
cmd.Connection = cn;
```

Comment: This got me as well :( I wish it would throw an error

Answer (score 10):

You have numerous problems in your code:

- First: The [`insert into` statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) requires a target datatable not the name of
  the MDF file
- Second: Employ the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) to close and dispose the connections
- Third: [Parametrized query](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) to avoid parsing problems and sql
  injections
- Fourth: You need to associate the connection to the command (Easily
  done at the [SqlCommand constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/877h0y3a.aspx))

  ```
  using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(.......))
  using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into table_name(Codigo,Nombre,Cantidad,Tipo)" + 
                            "values (@cod, @nom,@can,@tipo)", con))
  {
      cn.Open();
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod", comboBox1.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nom", textBox3.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@can", textBox1.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo", comboBox2.Text);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      MessageBox.Show("Acabas de agregar un producto");
  }
  ```

**EDIT**
The information provided by the link added by @RemusRusanu below is very important. The use of AddWithValue, whilst handy, could hinder the performance of your query. The correct approach should be the usage of a proper defined SqlParameter with both explicit datatype and parameter size.
As an example

```
SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@cod", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = comboBox1.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
```

But, of course, this requires that you check the exact datatype and size of your columns.

Comment: You have an extra semi-colon just before the first `{`. Also, even though you don't *need* curly braces after the first `using` statement, they would make it easier to see the scope.

Comment: Yes, copy paste Always fails me

Comment: I really disagree on the curly brace though

Comment: Here you go again adding hyperlinks, better formatting and typing much faster.  Touche! ;)

Comment: +1 but FYI `AddWithValue` is an anti-pattern. See [How Data Access Code Affects Database Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx)

Comment: I never use Parameters.AddWithValue, except when I don't know the datatype of my object (e.g. dynamic queries).

Answer (score 1):

You did not initialize your `SqlCommand` with a connection.  Also, you should really enclose everything here with `using`.  And consider using parametarized commands to avoid SQL Injection.

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Nova\Nova\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into databaseTableName (Codigo,Nombre,Cantidad,Tipo) values (@Codigo, @Nombre, @Cantidad, @Tipo)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Codigo", comboBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", textBox3.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cantidad", textBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tipo", comboBox2.Text);
                cmd.Connection = cn; //this was where the error originated in the first place.
                cn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Acabas de agregar un producto");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Truth!  Edited that out, was an oversight since I was trying to beat you to the answer ;)